# Difference between mutable copy and other creation methods

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Very often I need to change the contents of an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary`. Usually I go this way: `NSDictionary` -> create `NSMutableDictionary` and edit it -> Replace the original `NSDictionary` with the edited one (as non-mutable).

I know two ways for doing this:

1) Use `mutable copy` and `copy`:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = @{...};
NSMutableDictionary *dicToEdit = myDictionary.mutableCopy;
// Editing goes here`
myDictionary = dicToEdit.copy;
```

2) Using `arrayWithArray:` or `dictionaryWithDictionary:`

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = @{...};
NSMutableDictionary *dicToEdit = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:myDictionary];
// Editing goes here
myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dicToEdit];
```

Is there any difference between those two ways? Or are there any problems with one of the two ways?

Comment: They are equivalent.  And very likely share the same code.  `mutableCopy` is the "generic" method that is good for any class with a mutable twin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I would advise against using the property dot syntax `myDictionary.mutableCopy` instead of the method messaging syntax `[myDictionary mutableCopy]`. These mean exactly the same, but I would save the dot notation for real properties only (`copy` and `mutableCopy` are methods, not properties).

To answer your question, there may be subtle differences on how the internals of these two ways of copying Dictionaries work, but I believe that they are pretty much functionally equivalent.

I may recommend using `2)` because although slightly less succinct I'd say that it makes the code intentions clearer and more distinguishable from when you need two different `NSDictionary *` variables that point to the same dict.

Also, I'd say that `2)` makes the code semantics easier to understand. With `1)` you instruct the receiving object whether you want to obtain a *mutable* or *immutable* copy. With `2)` you don't care about whether or not the dictionary you are trying copy is mutable or immutable: mutability of the resulting dictionary just depends on the init method you used.

But ultimately it just boils down to personal preference I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding the dot syntax I have to mention that I use dot syntax wherever possible (as well as the modern syntax for dictionaries and arrays using {} and []). In my opinion the dot syntax makes the code much cleaner. Even though I think you are logically completely right, I prefer dots instead of a bunch of ]]]] at the end ;)

Comment: Up to you, it's just personal preference. Do note that *properties* are just *instance variables* backed up by *accessor methods* (the accessor methods can be auto-synthesized, manually implemented or a combination of both). So you are actually using methods in all cases, dot syntax or not. Personally, I prefer that my code makes readily understandable whether I'm using an explicitly defined method (I avoid the dot syntax) or I'm using the methods synthesized or implemented through a property (I use the dot syntax). In my experience this makes collaboration and maintenance easier. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Copy statement simply gives the immutable copy of an immutable type object.

Mutable Copy returns the mutable copy of immutable type object.

These have been explained greatly here ..... http://mobile.antonio081014.com/2012/09/speech-recognition-on-ios-with-openear.html

Thanks to Saroj Sharma . . ..